# Serverless V2: Value not found at "opt" source

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless, serverless-framework

We are currently using Serverless v2.0.0, and want to upgrade to the latest v3. As per their documentation, I am first upgrading to the latest v2.

We are using a python script to run serverless using the `subprocess` library, as we use secrets manager to get some cli params. The command string is as follows:

```
command = [
        "npm", "run",
        "serverless", "--", "deploy", 
        "--elastic", elasticHost,
...
    ]
```

The serverless.yml file looks like this:

```
service: devices
variablesResolutionMode: 20210326

plugins:
  - serverless-plugin-typescript
  - serverless-offline
  - serverless-domain-manager
  - serverless-prune-plugin

provider:
  name: aws
  versionFunctions: false
  environment:
    ES_HOST_URL: ${opt:elastic}
...
```

I can confirm that `elasticHost` does exist, I see it in the terminal when I run the script. However, when I run the script, I get the following error:

```
 > serverless "deploy" "--profile" "dev" "--aws-profile" "dev" "--elastic" "xxx" ...


 Serverless Error ----------------------------------------

  Cannot resolve serverless.yml: Variables resolution errored with:
    - Cannot resolve variable at "provider.environment.ES_HOST_URL": Value not found at "opt" source,
```

My package.json is as follows:

```
    "serverless": "^2.72.3",
    "serverless-api-compression": "^1.0.1",
    "serverless-domain-manager": "^6.0.3",
    "serverless-offline": "^8.7.0",
    "serverless-plugin-split-stacks": "^1.11.3",
    "serverless-plugin-tracing": "^2.0.0",
    "serverless-plugin-typescript": "^2.1.2",
    "serverless-prune-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "serverless-pseudo-parameters": "^2.6.1",
    "serverless-python-requirements": "^5.4.0",
    "serverless-step-functions": "^3.7.0",
```

If I replace `{opt:elastic}` with its value, I don't get the error, but I don't want it hardcoded. I'm trying to understand why I am getting this error, and how I can resolve it.

I haven't used serverless before, so any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error in the past. Lamentably, I didn't find a way to set dynamic values with opt command but I found another solution.

You can define environment vars in your serverless command and then use the env var in your serverless file so:

First, let's define a script in your package.json:

```
"scripts": {
   "serverless": “url=secondary serverless.. "  
}
```

Then in your YML file, you should have something like this:

```
environment:
    ES_HOST_URL: ${env:url, 'www.stackoverflow.com'}
```

This means, that if you don't set the env variable, this will set `www.stackoverflow.com` otherwise will be the value that you send from the command.

Finally, just run `npm run serverless` and that's it